# How to make mysql client prompt reflect the server you're connected to, not local one

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I have 2 servers - serverA and serverB, both have mysql server and mysql client. I have a reverse SSH tunnel set up from `serverB` to `serverA` so that I don't have to open ports up on `server B` to the internet. I access `serverB` from `serverA` by doing `mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 50003`

If I am logged into serverA and do `mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3306` I want the command line prompt to be `me@serverA [dbname]`.
If I am logged into serverA and do `mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 50003` I want the command line prompt to be `me@serverB [dbname]`.

**For these examples, I am always logged in to `serverA` and am connecting the mysql client to `serverA` or `serverB`**

Using the `prompt` directive in `/etc/my.cnf` on `serverA` and `serverB`,
if I do

```
[mysql]
prompt = \u@\h [\d]
```

then I get `me@127.0.0.1 [dbname]` on both of them.

if I do `prompt = \u@serverA [\d]` on ServerA and `prompt = \u@serverB [\d]` on serverB, then I get `me@serverA [dbname]` whether I'm trying to connect to `serverA` or `serverB`

So it looks like the command prompt is picking up the details for the server on `serverA` regardless of what I'm actually connecting to.

Is there any way I can make the prompt reflect what I'm actually connected to ?

Comment: This doesn't solve the question as written, but you can include the port in the prompt if the reason you want the prompt to be different is simply to tell the two connections apart. `prompt = \u@\h:\p [\d]` should work.

Comment: the port idea culd work, but without starting with --skip-slave-start both servers are the same, so what would be the need to connect to it locally.

Comment: [prompt](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) appears to be client-side setting. Maybe you could try control it from command line `mysql --prompt="\u@\h [\d]> "--host... --port...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prompt` setting is a client option. For connections from `serverA`, the only config file that will matter is the one on `serverA`. The reason you see `127.0.0.1` in your prompt for both connections is that, from the client's perspective, both connections connect to 127.0.0.1.

The MySQL client provides a mechanism for specifying option groups (command line argument [--default-groups-suffix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-group-suffix)), and you can use this to approximate what you are looking for. As an example for your needs, you can add the following to your `~/.my.cnf` file:

```
[clientserverA]
prompt = \u@serverA [\d]>
host = 127.0.0.1

[clientserverB]
prompt = \u@serverB [\d]>
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 50003
```

Using this, you can connect to MySQL using `mysql --defaults-group-suffix=serverA` or `mysql --defaults-group-suffix=serverB`. The client will use the appropriate host, port, and prompt for your connection based on the suffix you provide.

You can create a shell function that takes a suffix and creates the appropriate command line if you don't want to type that all out.